# How can I take output of command and populate array?

Tags: powershell

I have non-working code similar to the following:

```
$list = Get-VM | format-table VMElementName -HideTableHeaders | out-string
$array=@($list)

Write-Host $array[1]
```

What I end up is $array[0] filled with a list of data and no values in $array[1] or higher.

```
String1
String2
String3
```

What is the best way to parse this list to populate the array?

Comment: Rather than `format-table`, you should use `select-object`. That way you are still working with objects rather than strings. If you don't want the header, you can use the `-ExpandProperty` parameter.

Comment: To expand on @Entbark's comment, don't ever use `Format-Table` (or any other `Format-` cmdlet) unless you never want to use that data as data again. As soon as you format it, it's no longer usable. Also, [you shouldn't use `Write-Host`](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/donjones/archive/2012/04/06/2012-scripting-games-commentary-stop-using-write-host.aspx) in 90% of situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to get that is just select out the property you want with Select -ExpandProperty:

```
$array = Get-VM | select -ExpandProperty VMElementName
```

If you're running V3 or better, you can shorten that to:

```
$array = (Get-VM).VMElementName
```

Comment: You're welcome!  If that answers your question, please mark it as answered, so it doesn't remain forever as an "Unanswered Question".

Answer (score 1):

You don't need extra transformation logic. Just do the following

```
$array = ( Get-VM | format-table VMElementName -HideTableHeaders )

Write-Host $array[0]
```